# How do I get the mean values that are greater than .5 for my model?

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I am trying to build a classification model. One of the variables called specialty has 200 values. Based on a previous post I [saw](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/63239/dealing-with-categorical-variables), I decided I wanted to include the values that have the highest mean. I am thinking greater than 0.5. How would I filter the specialty to have only values greater than 0.5 for the mean?  I am trying to get my final dataset ready for machine learning.  Any advice is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly you want to "one-hot-encode" or dummy-encode your variable "specialty" so that it goes from an interval scaled variable to a binary variable where 1 == >.5 and 0 == <=.5 correct?

So seeing as you are in python the following code would create a new variable that does what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2['specialty_binned'] = np.digitize(df2['specialty'],bins=[0.5], right = True)
```

This would create a new variable in your data frame called 'specialty_binned' that is only 1s and 0s with 1 being values above 0.5 in the old variable.

Comment: Right now, the specialty category has 200 different specialties. It is not an interval scaled variable. It is categorical variable right now with text. I want to associate each category with a number so I can build a classification model. I was thinking of using a mean encoder. However, I think it might be difficult to interpret the model then.

Comment: This is a completely different task. In this case you have a factor variable that cannot be simply represented by numbers. Especially if those 200 specialities don't follow a strict ordinal value like e.g. typical survey responses (disagree to agree). You will have to one-hot-encode this variable which results in 200 new variables that are 1/0 scaled. Because that's a lot of variables it's best to cluster those 200 specialties before you do that so that you might have only 50 or so new variables.